# converting bmp image to byte array in android get blank image

Tags: android

I want to convert bmp image to byte array in android to print it using mobiwire Device,
I'm trying to do it using this function but the printer output in blank image

***This the function:***

```
 public static byte[] decodeBitmap(Bitmap bmp){
        int bmpWidth = bmp.getWidth();
        int bmpHeight = bmp.getHeight();

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); //binaryString list
        StringBuffer sb;


        int bitLen = bmpWidth / 8;
        int zeroCount = bmpWidth % 8;

        String zeroStr = "";
        if (zeroCount > 0) {
            bitLen = bmpWidth / 8 + 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < (8 - zeroCount); i++) {
                zeroStr = zeroStr + "0";
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < bmpHeight; i++) {
            sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int j = 0; j < bmpWidth; j++) {
                int color = bmp.getPixel(j, i);

                int r = (color >> 16) & 0xff;
                int g = (color >> 8) & 0xff;
                int b = color & 0xff;

                // if color close to white，bit='0', else bit='1'
                if (r > 160 && g > 160 && b > 160)
                    sb.append("0");
                else
                    sb.append("1");
            }
            if (zeroCount > 0) {
                sb.append(zeroStr);
            }
            list.add(sb.toString());
        }

        return hexList2Byte(commandList);
    }
```

I'm using Mobiwire device 2G in my test

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void convertToByteArray(BufferedImage image, String type) {
    String imageString = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, type, bos);
        byte[] imageBytes = bos.toByteArray();
        bos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: First encode the image to base64 string using above method and then encode base64 to byte array using below method.....

Answer (score -1):

This is **best and easy solution** to encode and decode an image to byte array.

for encoding bitmap image to byte array use.

```
 public String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image) {
        Bitmap immage = getResizedBitmap(image, 100, 80);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        immage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Log.d("Image Log:", imageEncoded);
        return imageEncoded;
    }
```

To get back image use

```
public Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) {
    try {
        byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```